# how to store several separate strings in a char** to use execvp?

Tags: c, linux, shell

i am coding a minishell, and i want to store my arguments in a char** and then call the execvp function with my char**

```
 int main(){
  char* buffer;
  printf(">");
  buffer = readbuff();
  printf("buffer :%s\n",buffer);
  exec(buffer);
  //printf("buffer :%s\n",buffer);
  free(buffer);
}
```

my function to read user input in a buffer

```
char* readbuff(){
  char* buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
  char* ptr = buff;
  fgets(buff,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);
  int i;
  for(i = 0;*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != '\n';++i){
    ptr++;
  }
  memset(ptr,'\0',1);
  return buff;
}
```

exec to execute the shell command

```
void exec(char* buff){
  char* ptr = buff;
  char command[30];
  int i = 0,j = 0;
  for(i=0;*ptr != ' ';++i){
    ptr++;
  }
  strncpy(commande,buff,i);
  command[i] = '\0';
  ptr++;
  char* ptr2 = ptr;
  while(*ptr2 != '\0'){ 
    if(*ptr2 == ' ')
      j++;
    ptr2++;
  }
```

j `will contain the number of arguments

```
  char** args = malloc(sizeof(char*)*j);
  char** ptrarg = args;
  for(int i = 0;i < j;i++){
    *ptrarg = ptr;
    while(*ptr !=  ' ')
      ptr++;
    ptr++;
    ptrarg ++;
  }

  pid_t son = fork();
  if(son == 0){ //son
    execvp(command,args);
    free(buff);
    free(args);
  }
  free(args);
}
```

My problem is the conversion of char* to char**

Comment: C++ or C, pick one.

Comment: Looks more like C code.

Comment: `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to char. So essentially a pointer to an array of `char*`s. So create an array of `char*`s and pass a pointer to the first one.

Comment: A C++ solution is to use a `std::vector` as storage for the strings.

Comment: How exactly may the  input look like?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry for the c++ tag

Comment: @alk the input is for example " ls file"

Comment: @JesperJuhl I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
char input[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
```

Steps to create arguments to `execvp()`:

- Count the blanks: 5
- Replace the blanks by `'\0'`s.
- Create an array of 5+1 `char*` (one more to be able to mark the end of the array):

  ```
  char ** ppc = malloc(6 * sizeof *ppc);
  ```
- Make the 1st point to the first word's 1st character:

  ```
  ppc[0] = input;
  ```
- Make the other 4 elements of `ppc` point the 1st `char` after each `'\0'`
- Mark the end of the array by setting its the last (the additional element) to `NULL`:

  ```
  ppc[5] = NULL;
  ```
- call `execvp` like this

  ```
  execvp(ppc[0], ppc);
  ```

Complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() and  EXIT_xxx macros */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */
#include <string.h> /* for strchr() and strtok() */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  char input[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
  size_t words = 0;

  {
    char * pc = input;
    while ((pc = strchr(pc, ' ')))
    {
      ++pc;

      if (!*pc && *pc != *(pc - 1)) /* Skip successive blanks. */
      {
        ++words;
      }
    }
  }

  {
    char ** ppc = malloc((words + 1) * sizeof *ppc);
    if (NULL == ppc)
    {
      perror("malloc() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    {
      size_t i = 0;
      ppc[i] = strtok(input, " ");

      while (NULL != (ppc[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ")));
    }

    {
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if (-1 == pid)
      {
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if (0 == pid)
      {
        execvp(ppc[0], ppc);
        perror("execvp() failed");
        result = EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }

    free(ppc);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically the same answer as above, implemented slight differently. quick answer to your problem "My problem is the conversion of char* to char**" => you have to create(malloc) a char* array to the count of individual char* elements. then for each element in char** you have to malloc char array and copy the chars. which is implemented below. cheers !

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

char* readbuff()
{
  char* buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
  char* ptr= buff;
  memset(ptr,'\0',BUFFER_SIZE);
  fgets(buff,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);
 // int i;
  //for(i = 0;*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != '\n';++i){
    //ptr++;
  //}
  //memset(ptr,'\0',1);
  return buff;
}


void exec(char* buff)
{
  char* ptr = buff;
  char command[30];
  int i = 0,j = 0;
  for(i=0;*ptr != ' ';++i){
    ptr++;
  }

  strncpy(command,buff,i);
  command[i] = '\0';
  //ptr++;
  char* ptr2 = ptr;
  ptr++;
  while(*ptr2 != '\0'){
    if(*ptr2 == ' ')
      j++;
    ptr2++;
  }

  char** args = malloc(sizeof(char*)*j);
  //char** ptrarg = args;
  int k=0;
  char* ptrstart = ptr;

  for(int i = 0;i < j;i++)
  { 
    //*ptrarg = ptr;
    ptrstart = ptr;
    k=0;
    while((*ptr !=  ' ') && (*ptr != '\0') )
    {     
      k++;
      ++ptr;
    }
    args[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(k));
    strncpy(args[i], ptrstart, k-1);
    args[i][k]= '\0';

    ptr++;
    //ptrarg ++;
  }

  printf("command %s", command);
  printf("args[0] %s", args[0]);

  pid_t son = fork();
  if(son == 0){ //son
    execvp(command,args);
    //free(buff);
    //free(args);
  }
  free(args);

}

int main()
{
  char* buffer;
  printf(">");
  buffer = readbuff();
  printf("buffer :%s\n",buffer);
  exec(buffer);
  //printf("buffer :%s\n",buffer);
  free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: In case  `execvp()`  fails `args` and `buffer` are freed twice.